# Отправка POST-запроса на сервер

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Задача - отправить на сервер запрос (либо параметры для запроса на сервере) и получить выборку. Однако с отправкой возникли проблемы.

В RegConnection передаю через execute два параметра: param[0] это текст из EditText (условие запроса) и param[1] это номер выбранного элемента спиннера. Однако при передаче данных через urlConnection.setRequestProperty (вообще не понимаю нужен ли в этой ситуации буфер выходных данных и как без него, однако для получения значения обратно нужен входной) запрос происходит через раз, и то, даже если он приходит (и создается тхт-лог), то POST-параметры пустые.

```
class RegConnection extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://r-rp.su/php/android.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("spinneritem", params[1]);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("value", params[0]);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write("Hello");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        urlConnection.connect();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
} }
```

PHP

```
     <?php

$spinneritem = intval($_POST['spinneritem']);
$value = $_POST['value'];
$query = "";
file_put_contents('android.txt', $spinneritem." - item ".$value." - value\n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);

switch($spinneritem)
{
    case 0:
        $query = "SELECT FLIGHTS.NUM, FLIGHTS.START_TIME, FLIGHTS.AIRPORT_TARGET FROM FLIGHTS
                            INNER JOIN startings ON startings.flight_num=flights.num
                            INNER JOIN PLANES ON startings.plane_code=PLANES.PLANE_CODE +
                            WHERE PLANES.TYPE=?;";

        break;
}

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('*данные*);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($value);
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $ret = json_encode($res);
    file_put_contents('android.txt', $ret." - returned value \n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
    echo $res;


    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    file_put_contents('android.txt', $e->getMessage()." - exception \n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
    die();
}

?>

    введите сюда код
```

Comment: Не пробывал пользоватся retrofit?

Comment: Я первую неделю прикоснулся к Джаве, мне нужно до конца недели сдать задание с подключением к БД и исполнением запросов, такая штука как retrofit (почитал на хабре) для меня сложновата.

Сейчас подправил и разобрался с буфером, однако запрос как будто вообще не доходит до сервера. На выходе 0 ошибок и нет исключений, все переменные и параметры правильные. Однако до сервера не доходит (.htaccess не блокирует)

Comment: у ретрофита есть логи и он гараздо проще и понятнее, чем ты думаешь и делаешь сейчас, так что советую разобратся с ним. С ним разбираться не больше часа, просто по инструкции все сделать